# Data structure needed for file structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Say you have a file called a.txt, which has its contents as :

```
module ABC
  DEF def(); // Calls/Instantiation for other module.
  XYZ xyz(); // Calls/Instantiation for other module.
  // It can calls/instantiate all other module available in the file.
  ....
endmodule

module DEF
  ABC abc();
  XYZ xyz();
  ....
endmodule

...
...

module XYZ
  ABC abc();
  XYZ xyz();
  ....
endmodule
```

What is the data structure you would recommend for this kind of file structure? Primarily, I would like to show an hierarchical structure. Like :

```
ABC
  def
  xyz
  ...

DEF
  abc
  xyz
  ...

and so on.
```

-> I have thought of an naive algorithm which is related to linked lists but I am not happy with that. It would not be memory efficient. Something like:

There will be nodes based upon the declaration of modules.

```
[ABC]->[DEF]->....->[XYZ]
```

and then from each node, instantiations will come down. So, complete data structure would look like as :

```
[ABC]->[DEF]->....->[XYZ]
  |      |            |
[DEF]  [ABC]->....->[ABC]
  |      |
[XYZ]  [XYZ]->....->[DEF]
....   ....         ....
```

Comment: How about a graph?

Comment: @cricket_007, Yes. We can consider but how will you model it?

Comment: @HemantBhargava depends on what you want to be able to do with reasonable efficiency.

Comment: Both Neo4j and OrientDB (the two most popular graph databases) have embedded modes (no server necessary)

Comment: The data structure you want will depend on what you're going to do with the information. So far, you haven't told us how you're going to use this data, so it's rather difficult to suggest a data structure.